# How do I make a animation on hover like Netflix?

Tags: css, animation, streaming, css-animations

I am working on a streaming service. I want to make a zoom in like Netflix when you hover on a title. How would I accomplish this, I am really rusty with animations.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  

  .container {
      display: flex;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    .item {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      flex: 1 2 0px;
      transition: transform 1000ms;
    }


    .container:hover .item {
      transform: translateX(-25%);
    }

    .item:focus ~ .item,
    .item:hover ~ .item {
      transform: translateX(25%);
    }

    .container .item:focus,
    .container .item:hover {
      transform: scale(2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .item img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#architecture" class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/hills" alt="Hills"></a>
  <a href="#nature" class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" alt="Nature"></a>
  <a href="#forest" class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/forest" alt="Forest"></a>
  <a href="#games" class="item"><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/games" alt="Games"></a>
</div>
```

This is a small reference to the hover effects and animations. For more knowledge try [Try this, even I learnt from this.](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-re-create-a-nifty-netflix-animation-in-css/)